# Font size adjusting function in Android Webview

Tags: android

I have been developing an Android RSS news reader.I want to add two buttons for adjusting the font size when a news is loaded in Webview.Can anyone tell me, how can I create  a function for changing the font size of Webview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `WebView` has a `WebSettings` object associated with it. You can get the object by calling `getSettings` on your `WebView`. The `WebSettings` object has a method called `setTextZoom(int)` which allows you to set the text size. The `int` argument is the percentage zoom and defaults to 100.

So, maybe something like this:

```
increaseFontButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setTextZoom( (int)(settings.getTextZoom() * 1.1) );
    }
}
```

And something similar to decrease the font.

edit: I should have mentioned that `setTextZoom` and `getTextZoom` were introduced in API 14. If you are targeting prior to that API, you should use `settings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize)` in which you pass in one of the [WebSettings.TextSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.TextSize.html) enums (SMALLEST, SMALLER, NORMAL, LARGER, or LARGEST).

Comment: @BasimSherif I should have mentioned that the methods I used in that snippet are API 14 only. If you are targeting something earlier, you'll have to use `setTextSize`. See my edit above.